# Can you find a fictional short story about time travel that was in 1990s American language arts textbooks?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

Group of kids travel to the past and to the future,  where humans have evolved and reduced language down to a simple word.  The word "sellup" has infinite meanings and is their only form of communication.

Most likely in a McGraw language arts textbook from 1998, 1999 or 2000 for grades 4 or 5.

Comment: Are you sure the word is _sellup_? This seems like it should be an easy Google using that word but I'm not finding anything.

Comment: Any idea of what grade level for the language arts. You can access some on Archive.org, so might be able to look through them. Also any idea on the cover might help.

Comment: There was an episode of Ugly Americans that explains the ManBirds' language with a very similar (although more offensive) story. I thought the UA wiki may have some trivia with the inspiration, but not luck. This may not help much but it may be an angle of investigation. https://uglyamericans.fandom.com/wiki/Manbird